# Rally User Management Ruby Scripts

Tags: ruby, rally

I have a workspace w1, w2, w3 and w4. Using Ruby scripts, i added a workspace admin user to w4. In my spreadsheet, i only had one row for the same. After i ran the scripts, apart from giving permissions as workspace admin to w4, i see that this user is also given a user access to W1 and viewer to the project underneath it. 
If i create a 'No Access' entries for this user corresponding to w1, it still behaves the same unless this 'No Access' row is at the end of the spreadsheet. 
Once i added the 'No Access' entry for this user corresponding to W1 as the last row in the spreadsheet with the first row being 'admin' corresponding to W4, then running the ruby script creates the permissions as i wanted (which is admin to workspace W4 only). Is this the expected behaviour or am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

What you are observing is expected behavior. When Rally's Webservices API initially creates a user, it does so with a default Workspace/Project Permission Pair corresponding to Workspace User/Project Viewer for the default Workspace of the user initiating the create, with a Project Viewer permission for the alphabetically first Project in the Workspace. After creation, the user management scripts process the permission grants based on the row entries in your CSV file and create a Workspace Administrator WorkspacePermission, but does not delete, the existing ProjectPermission. This is discussed in the README for the scripting tool.